# How to use an object in ViewModel coming from code behind

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a set of pages between which I navigate and between which I need to pass some parameters, namely some objects of the type of my Models. When I navigate to a page I Setup this new page's constructor with a parameter of the type of the object I need, so the class is implemented as follows:

```
public partial class ArtigoEdit : ContentPage
{
    EditionsViewModel viewModel;
    public ArtigoEdit(Models.Artigo artigo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = viewModel = new EditionsViewModel();

        this.viewModel.Artigo = artigo;
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm also using the MVVM pattern and on its side I have a variable "Artigo" to which I want to assign the object my constructor receives:

```
Models.Artigo artigo;
public Models.Artigo Artigo
{
    get { return artigo; }
    set { artigo = value; this.Notify("Artigo"); }
}
```

The problem is that if I try to access the attributes of this object in order to change the way they are displayed and bind to these new variables instead the object is null when the page opens so the variables are not shown:

```
string tipoArtigo = "";
public string TipoArtigo
{
    get { return tipoArtigo; }
    set 
    { 
        if (Artigo != null)
        {
            if(Artigo.TipoArtigo == "P")
                tipoArtigo = "Produto";
            else if (Artigo.TipoArtigo == "S")
                tipoArtigo = "Serviço";
            else if (Artigo.TipoArtigo == "O")
                tipoArtigo = "Outro";
            else if (Artigo.TipoArtigo == "I")
                tipoArtigo = "Imposto";
            else
                tipoArtigo = value;
        }
        this.Notify("TipoArtigo"); 
    }
}
```

Is this not the correct way of doing this? If not, what is my alternative? Beware that my ViewModels all implemente a `ViewModelBase` class that itself implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so do not worry about that! :)

Comment: Where are each of this pieces of code located (viewmodel, code behind)? How do you call/create your pages?

Comment: In first look it look fine to me, please ensure your passing values are received in ctor.

Comment: @Kilazur they are pieces of my code Behind (1), and then view Model (2 and 3) for the same page.

Comment: @FCouto ok, how do you pass your Artigo to your page? How/where is this page created?

Comment: @Kilazur A simple navigation honestly, I just PushAsync the page and pass the object in its constructor from a listView, using itemSelected property.

Comment: Try creating the viewmodel object first, assign to it and then set it as the `BindingContext`. Like this: `viewModel = new EditionsViewModel();         this.viewModel.Artigo = artigo; BindingContext = viewModel;`

Comment: @GeraldVersluis It did not work unfortunatly. I might add that this ViewModel is shared between two pages and both require me using objects that I receive in each of these pages. The problem is that if I simply bind to the property of the object it WORKS...but If I try to access the variable in the viewModel and work with it to give a dependent value to other variable and bind this second variable...it DOES NOT work. :|

Comment: I think you could save yourself a lot of time and headache by adopting some framework to do this stuff for you ;-) Did you have a look at FreshMvvm?

Comment: I did not, I was trying to keep it as simple as possible but I might take a look if it is your sugestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I'm sorry for disturbing and I thank to all the people who tried to help. What was happening was: I was binding these variables to an Entry, but for some reason it was not expanding to fit the size of information so although it was there it did not appear to be...luckily I've noticed it.